# Is it possible to solve $2c\sin^2(x)-a\sin(x-y)-k\cos(x)-c=0$ for $x$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, multivariable-calculus, trigonometry

> I have this trigonometric equation:
> $$2c\sin^2(x)-a\sin(x-y)-k\cos(x)-c=0$$
> where $c, a, k$ - some constants. Need to solve for $x$.

Tried to rewrite equation as:
$$c \cdot \cos(2x)+a \sin(x-y)+k\cos(x)=0$$
But it still difficult to get expression for x.

Maybe try to use Taylor series to find approximate solution? But I would like to find exact value if it's possible.

Comment: I'm sorry but I gotta ask. When you were picking which letter to use for the third constant coefficient to go along with $a$ and $c$, is there a reason you skipped all the way to $k$? It doesn't matter of course, as far as the math is concerned. But my OCD brain really wishes you'd just change it to $b$.... ^_^

Comment: You do need first one variable. You have $y=x-\arcsin(A)$ where $A=\dfrac{k\cos(x)+2c\cos^2(x)-c}{a}$

Comment: It is possible (but not pretty afaik) you can do $\sin(x) = \frac{e^{ix} - e^{-ix}}{2i}$ and $\cos(x) = \frac{e^{ix} + e^{-ix}}{2}$, let $z = e^{ix}$, and solve a quartic equation for $z$.